# Increasing Wasteland Carry Capacity for Stimpacks/Radaway

Tags: fallout-shelter

Currently when sending dwellers into the Wasteland, the maximum Stimpack and Radaway carry capacity is twenty-five each. Is there a way to raise this capacity?

Reading on the GameFAQs forums [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168521-fallout-shelter/72370902) and [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168521-fallout-shelter/72120145), the answer at first appears to be "no", but the information is also two years old. However, the first mentioned a potential exploit that once existed but has since been "patched out"; I believe said exploit is what is referred to in this [article](https://falloutshelteraddicts.wordpress.com/2015/06/26/the-ultimate-wastelander-6-easy-steps-to-unlimited-stimpaks/). Investigating the Bethesda community forums for Fallout Shelter, I was unable to find anything particularly relevant to the specific question.

So: Is there either a) an in-game mechanic for increasing wasteland carry capacity for stimpacks/radaway, similar to Strength allowing the increase of loot carry capacity, or b) a new exploit that allows for the same function as the patched-out one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to increase a dwellers carry capacity for Stimpacks/Radaway.

The reason for this is because firstly, as dwellers level up, they become more resilient to damage and radiation, therefore the need for more Stimpacks and Radaway becomes redundant. At max level, in standard gear, I've had dwellers wandering for almost 4 days straight.

Secondly, when a dweller levels up, they recover all lost health, reducing the need for Stimpacks.

And finally, dwellers are also limited by their carrying capacity. So regardless of how many Stimpacks/Radaway they may/may not have, if their inventory is full, they will return anyway. At max level, this is a more than likely scenario.

Comment: Note that max HP is affected by END, and is **not** retroactive.  A dweller with 17 END at level 1 then leveling to 50 will get the maximum amount of HP.  Subsequently, a dweller with 11 END or higher is completely immune to radiation damage.